# jQuery Isotope filtering using Twitter Bootstrap dropdown

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-isotope

Looking to implement Isotope filter options with Bootstrap dropdown/popup menu without much luck. The Bootstrap menu stops working, as in it stops toggling and closing when selected, although the isotope filtering works on clicking. Both (isotope and bootstrap menu) are working fine individually. Any help is appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-input clearfix">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle form-control" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <span data-bind="label">All</span> <span class="caret"></span>
                          </button>
                          <ul id="work-menu" class="dropdown-menu " role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="current">All</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-filter=".web">Web Projects</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-filter=".webapp">Web Applications</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-filter=".mobile">Mobile Projects</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" data-filter=".graphic">Graphic Designs</a></li>
                          </ul>

</div>
```

JS:

```
var $container = $('.works-wrap');
$container.isotope({
    filter: '*',
    animationOptions: {
        duration: 750,
        easing: 'linear',
        queue: false
    }
});


//Bootstrap dropdown menu
$( document.body ).on( 'click', '#work-menu li', function( event ) {

       var $target = $( event.currentTarget );
       $target.closest( '.btn-group' ).find( '[data-bind="label"]' ).text( $target.text() ).end()
       .children( '.dropdown-toggle' ).dropdown( 'toggle' );

       return false;

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I just got working using Bootstrap 3's Dropdown and Isotope...the JS. I saw your post a few days ago and was hoping there would be an answer, so I've been struggling for a day or so myself until this morning. I wrote this for a joomla 3 module and just got it working using the dropdown:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery.getScript('//cdn.jsdelivr.net/isotope/1.5.25/jquery.isotope.min.js',function(){
  /* activate jquery isotope */
  jQuery("#posts").imagesLoaded( function(){
  jQuery("#posts").isotope({
   filter: '*',   
    itemSelector : '.item',
    layoutMode : 'fitRows',
    getSortData : {
      category : function(jQueryelem) {
        return jQueryelem.attr("data-category");
        } 
      }
    });
    });
  });

jQuery("#sort-mike a").click(function(event){
  var selector = jQuery(this).attr("data-filter");
  event.preventDefault();
  jQuery("#posts").isotope({ 
    filter: selector,
    sortBy : 'category',  
    sortAscending : true
  });
  return true;


});



});
```

Then the html and php:

```
<?php 


 echo "<section>";
 echo "<div class=\"container\">";
 echo "<div class=\"row\">";

 echo "<div class=\"col-md-12\">";
 echo "<div class=\"dropdown\">";
 echo "<a id=\"dLabel\" role=\"button\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\" data-target=\"#\" href=\"#\">Divcom <span class=\"caret\"></span></a>";
 echo "<ul id=\"sort-mike\" class=\"dropdown-menu\" role=\"menu\" aria-labelledby=\"dLabel\">";
 echo "<li><a href=\"#\" data-filter=\"*\" >All</a></li>";
 echo "<li><a href=\"#\" data-filter=\".dcportland\" >Portland</a></li>";
 echo "<li><a href=\"#\" data-filter=\".dccanada\">Canada</a></li>";
 echo "<li><a href=\"#\" data-filter=\".dcuk\">UK</a></li>";
 echo "<li><a href=\"#\" data-filter=\".dcaustralia\">Australia</a></li>";
 echo "<li><a href=\"#\" data-filter=\".dcindia\">India</a></li>";
 echo "<li><a href=\"#\" data-filter=\".dchongkong\">Hong Kong</a></li>";
 echo "<li><a href=\"#\" data-filter=\".dcthailand\">Thailand</a></li>";
 echo "<li><a href=\"#\" data-filter=\".dcbroadcast\" >Broadcast</a></li>";
 echo "</ul>";
 echo "</div>";   
 echo "</div>";
 echo "</div>";
 echo "<p></p>";



 echo "<div id=\"posts\" class=\"row\">";

      foreach ($rows as $row) {

 echo '<div class="item col-md-2 '. $row->producer .' '. $row->producer2 .' "     data-category="'. $row->producer .' '. $row->producer2 .' '. $row->producer3 .' '. $row->producer4 .'">';
 echo '<div class="industries">';
 echo '<a href="' . $row->webaddress . '" target="_blank"><img src="' . $row->logo . '"   class="img-responsive"></a>';

 echo '<span class="location"><br />' . $row->location . '</span>';
 echo '<span class="date">';
 echo '<br />' . date('F d, Y', strtotime('' . $row->startdate . ''));
 echo '</span>';
 echo       "</div>";
 echo       "</div>";

     }

echo    "</div>"; 
echo   "</div>"; 
echo "</section>";  

?>
```